# Convert PHP variable date to local date in Hebrew

Tags: php, date, variables, localization, hebrew

I convert a string in PHP to a date variable and need to print it in the local date in Hebrew language. I print the date to the page with `date('M');` which results in `March`, in English, and my desired result is to print it in the local Hebrew language which should result in `מרץ`.

I know that there is way to create array and translate each name of month and day manually but I'm interested to convert the date variable that I have into `$date` into the local PHP date in Hebrew language. What will be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the locale first:

```
if (setlocale(LC_ALL, 'he_IL') === false) {
    throw new Exception("Locale not available on this machine.");
}
```

And then use strftime(), as date() doesn't respect locale settings:

```
echo strftime('%B');
```

Also note that your system needs to have the correct locale installed, which you can list via the command line with `locale -a`.

Comment: How I can use `strftime();` to print the date variable?

Comment: [Read the docs.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) You can pass a timestamp as the second parameter.

Comment: I set the local before but `echo strftime('%B');` print the month in English as `March` instead in Hebrew.

Comment: _"Also note that your system needs to have the correct locale installed."_

Comment: Some systems may require use of `'he_IL.utf-8'` (My CentOS box does. My Mac doesn't) Alex already mentioned that `locale -a` will show all available.